# How to calculate and display percent of screen that has no content

Tags: calculations

In this example, I want to insert the percentage of the page that isn't blank including the strikeouts and the percentage itself.

I tried doing both a Google search and a TeX.SE search but nothing came up.

[image]

Comment: i really doubt that your question is `latex` related ...

Comment: @Zarko Why not? You can make graphics, animation,  with additional packages. This is also still typesetting-related. I think this is like the ones shown in the TeX showcase.

Comment: if you say so, ... but your question seems to be related to percentage calculation and very elementary geometry. if not, than provide some latex code,  by which you try to solve your problem.

Comment: @Zarko I have no idea on how to, that's why I'm asking. Tried a Google and TeX.SE search and nothing came up.

Comment: there's a book that says "this page is intentionally left 99.something% blank.". maybe you could ask the author how to do that.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this endeavour is silly, use 42, which is correct 100% of times.

Comment: Even though I already found a (really tedious, since it took me 4 hours to finish it) way on how to do it without asking that author, I still want to see a TeX or Metafont workaround directly involves the rendering or the design of the fonts.

Comment: Genuine question... *why* do you actually want to do this?

Comment: What should be the answer if you type `\textcolor{white}{This page is not entirely blank.}` (of course, with `\thispagestyle{empty}`)?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a possible solution through scripting. First, the TeX document (`mydoc.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
This page is not entirely blank.
\end{document}
```

I could embed the conversion inside my script, but let us simplify the process:

```
$ convert mydoc.pdf -density 300 -flatten img.png
```

Now, consider the following Python code (`howmuch.py`):

```py
from PIL import Image
ps = Image.open('img.png').getdata()
bp = 0
for p in ps:
    if p != 255:
        bp = bp + 1
print('Your page is {:.4f}% blank.'.format((1 - bp / float(len(ps))) * 100))
```

Then it is just a matter of issuing:

```
$ python howmuch.py 
Your page is 99.9104% blank.
```

Done.

**Update:** Thanks to Torbjørn, here is an improved version which attempts to guess the closest value based on previous iterations. I believe the logic behind the code is pretty self-explanatory.

```py
from PIL import Image
from subprocess import call

def calculate(template, context, engine = 'pdflatex'):
    with open('page.tex', 'w') as page:
        page.write(template.format(**context))
    call([engine, 'page.tex'])
    call(['convert', 'page.pdf', '-density', '300', '-flatten', 'img.png'])
    ps = Image.open('img.png').getdata()
    bp = 0
    for p in ps:
            bp += 1 if p != 255 else 0
    return (1 - bp / float(len(ps))) * 100

doc = r'''
\documentclass{{article}}
\begin{{document}}
\thispagestyle{{empty}}
This page is not entirely blank.

It is {percentage}\% empty.
\end{{document}}
'''

guess = 99.8
max_attempts = 99
attempt_count = 0
tolerance = 0.01

while attempt_count < max_attempts:
    d = calculate(doc, { 'percentage' : guess }) - guess
    if abs(d) < tolerance:
        break
    else:
        guess = guess - 0.01 if d < 0 else guess + 0.01
    attempt_count += 1

print('Done.')
```

In this particular case, after 5 iterations, we achieve convergence. `:)`

[image: Quack]

And there we go.

Comment: I think the OP want's the percentage typeset to the PDF as well....

Comment: @jfbu: yes, you are right. Torbjørn and I were talking about this in the chat room. `:)` The script just calculates the blank area, so it might be good to include a percentage placeholder in the TeX document and fiddle with the result. We believe that, at some point, it will converge. `:)`

Comment: I trust it will :) anyway if you keep trace of previous one then python side will be easy place to add some stopping criteria say if does not move by more than 0.01% ...

Comment: hmm my last comment is a bit confused. Looking forward to see your final solution `;-)`

Comment: @jfbu: oh no, the pressure is on! `:)` I will take a look later on, otherwise I will be procrastinating too much (and my thesis won't be written at all). Another possible workaround is to ignore the decimal places. `:P`

Comment: Inspiration: https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/04f9058e59b45bc6e73e0bc713bfd1a0 You know a lot more programming than me though, so you can probably see if there are any bad ideas in there.

Comment: @jfbu: code updated. `:)`

Comment: seems the fixed point was not repulsive, congrats `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Although I have found a way to display it, the method I used wasn't using either calculations or LaTeX.

So, my question is still unsolved.

1) Compile with PdfLaTeX or XeTeX

2) Open PDF with Photoshop

3) Rasterize with at least 3000 dpi, grayscale, no anti-aliasing

4) Open Histogram and look at the percentile value of the one in the far right (the one in the far left is the amount of black)

5) If the percentile value is equal to the percent you typed, then well done. If not, then change the percent you typed and repeat steps 1 to 5 until you can arrive a correct result.

[image]